# mongodb remove specific array item from multiple documents (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to remove a specific array item from multiple documents. Let's say we have the following documents:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  email: 'person1@email.com',
  tasks: [
     { title: 'some titleA', uuid: 'uuidA'},
     { title: 'some titleB', uuid: 'uuidB'},
     { title: 'some titleC', uuid: 'uuidC'},
  ]
},
{
  _id: ...,
  email: 'person2@email.com',
  tasks: [
     { title: 'some titleA', uuid: 'uuidA'},
     { title: 'some titleB', uuid: 'uuidB'},
     { title: 'some titleC', uuid: 'uuidC'},
  ]
},
{
  _id: ...,
  email: 'person3@email.com',
  tasks: [
     { title: 'some titleA', uuid: 'uuidA'},
     { title: 'some titleB', uuid: 'uuidB'},
     { title: 'some titleC', uuid: 'uuidC'},
  ]
}
```

then, given a list of emails, say `person1@email.com` and `person2@email.com` remove from the  `tasks` array of any documents matching those emails the array item where `uuid` value is `uuidB`.

the result should be

```
{
  _id: ...,
  email: 'person1@email.com',
  tasks: [
     { title: 'some titleA', uuid: 'uuidA'},
     { title: 'some titleC', uuid: 'uuidC'},
  ]
},
{
  _id: ...,
  email: 'person2@email.com',
  tasks: [
     { title: 'some titleA', uuid: 'uuidA'},
     { title: 'some titleC', uuid: 'uuidC'},
  ]
},
{
  _id: ...,
  email: 'person3@email.com',
  tasks: [
     { title: 'some titleA', uuid: 'uuidA'},
     { title: 'some titleB', uuid: 'uuidB'},
     { title: 'some titleC', uuid: 'uuidC'},
  ]
}
```

this is what I have tried so far:

```
 var emails = ['person1@email.com', 'person2@email.com']
 model.updateMany({
    email: { $in: emails },
 }, {
    $pull: {
        tasks: {
            $elemMatch: { uuid: uuid }
        }
    }
})
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is an [**`query`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [**`projection`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator and not an [**`update operator`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/). Therefore you cannot use it here.

You need to use "absolute" object structures

```
model.updateMany(
  { "email": { "$in": emails }},
  { "$pull": { "tasks": { "uuid": uuid }}}
)
```